# Cannot Find Symbol Fout.close and Fout.write

Tags: java

I am new in java  programming, so I cannot find the solution for my code error. Here is my code -

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class FileOutputStream1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream1 Fout = new FileOutputStream1();
            Fout.write(60);
            Fout.close();
            System.out.println("Success..");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing these cannot find symbol so many time, please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `FileOutputStream1` and not `FileOutputStream`? Is it your own custom class?

Comment: I saved these file name as FileOutputStream1

Comment: Very confusing to name your class `FileOutputStream1`

Comment: at first may consider looking for some basic java tutorial where file handling is shown. and please take a look on name conventions(variable names start lowercase)

Comment: Class name should be unique i think, that is why i am using class name as FileOutputStream1.

Comment: just to mention: the error means that `Fout` does not have a `close` nor a `write`... the class `FileOutputStream1` does not have these methods

Comment: You do not need to make filename similar to the one you are using in your code, `FileOutputStream` in this case. While not a great name but something even like `FileWriteUtil` or any other name respresenting the responsibility of the class would be better than `FileOutputStream1`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Fout` to be a `FileOutputStream`, not a `FileOutputStream1`? If you're expecting it to write to a file, you'll need to provide the filename in the constructor, too. (Now would be a good time to learn about Java naming conventions, and also think about more meaningful names...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `FileOutputStream` (and not `FileOutputStream1`) and pass the file path to `constructor`, e.g.:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("path_to_FileOutputStream1_file");
fout.write(60);
fout.close();
System.out.println("Success..");
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) the javadoc for `FileOutputStream` class.

Comment: Sir still I am facing the problem.

Comment: @MohitSoni have you got `import java.io.FileOutputStream;` statement in your class? I don't think it should show `cannot find symbol` error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
    FileOutputStream1 Fout = new FileOutputStream1();
    Fout.write(60);
```

You declare `Fout` to refer to an instance of your `FileOutputStream1` class, and then you attempt to call an instance method called `write` on that instance.

The problem is that *you have not declared a `write` method* for your `FileOutputStream1` class.  That's why the compiler is saying "cannot find symbol".

You seem to be wanting your `FileOutputStream1` to be related to `java.io.FileOutputStream` ... which *does* have a write method.  However, they are not related.

Answer (score 0):

You coded as `Fout.write(60);` and `Fout.close();` so while compiling, `javac` will will look for methods `write()` and `close()` in the class with corresponding reference `Fout` which is `FileOutputStream1`. But there are no such methods in `FileOutputStream1`.

Actually these are methods found in `FileOutputStream` which is predefined in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code with these

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
public class FileOutputStreamExample 
    {  
    public static void main(String args[])
        {    
           try
               {    
             FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("F:\\File.txt");    
             fout.write(60);    
             fout.close();    
             System.out.println("success...");    
             }
             catch(Exception e)
                {
                System.out.println(e);
                }    
      }
}
```

but then error says that cannot access Exception
 catch(Exception e)